# Long Sync IO: Scheduler X had 1 Sync IOs in nonpreemptive mode longer than 1000 ms

Tags: sql-server

in SQL 2014 SP3 i got quite a few "Long Sync IO: Scheduler x had 1 Sync IOs in nonpreemptive mode longer than 1000 ms". what is the size that SQL reports for the sync IO, is it 8K or varies based on activity: data read/transaction write/or lazy writes or checkpoint activities?

Thank you,